# when a button is clicked call an alert

Tags: jquery

i have a button thats nested in a table,as follows

```
 <div class="marketoptionslist">
 <table>
 <thead>        
 <tr>          
 <th>#</th>          
 <th>Description</th>          
 <th>Current</th>          
 <th>Previous</th> 
 </tr></thead>      
 <tbody>    
 <tr class="marketoptionrow OP">      
 <td class="DisplayNumber">1</td>      
 <td class="DisplayName"> Flour</td>      
 <td><a class="button">click</a></td></tr> //when this button is clicked an alert must be displayed
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

When i click the above button i want to produce an alert.I have tried the following and nothing seems to be detecting the click and producing the alert

```
function test()
{
 if $("marketoptionslist a button").click(function (){
 alert("clickeddddd");
}
}test();
function test()
{
 if $("marketoptionslist marketoptionrow OP a button").click(function (){
 alert("clickeddddd");
}
}test();
```

is there another way to detect if the button is clicked?

Comment: This is really jQuery 101, and the kind of simple task you should be able to research yourself. I'd suggest starting with http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: use `$(".marketoptionslist a.button")` instead of `$("marketoptionslist a button")`

Answer (score 0):

Simple Your script code like bellow remove else you did

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".button").click(function (){
 alert("clickeddddd");
});
});
</scirpt>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener on your class `.button`. It's enough

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  console.log("class button clicked ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">click</button>
<button class="button">click</button>
<button class="button">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use event bubbling .

```
$(document).on("click" , ".button" , function()
{
   alert("Button clicked.");
});
```